# Recommend Indian cookbooks for a beginner/intermediate amateur

Tags: cookbook

I would like to experience more Indian food but I need recipes ideas and to learn some more cooking techniques.

What are some good cookbooks for a beginner/intermediate level amateur "chef"?

Answer (score 3):

I have the [*Easy Indian Cookbook* by Manju Malhi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1844836193). I've found it to be good. The recipes don't usually call for ingredients I can't find in my standard grocery store (though for lamb I need to go to Whole Foods), are explained well, and the measurements are in US-standard units (i.e., measuring flour by volume in cups). It also has meal suggestions (i.e., a meat dish, a veggie dish, a dessert, and a drink), though I've never used these (I'm generally cooking for one, so more than one dish is usually overkill).

Each recipe ore section has a brief (sometimes *very* brief) overview of the region the recipe(s) came from and the evolution of the dish to what it is today.